# TypeScript, Backbone and RequireJS - public / private issue when creating collection

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, typescript

I'm trying to get started using TypeScript and Backbone, with all of my classes in separate files, using RequireJS. I have a model and a collection:

EntityModel.ts:

```
/// <reference path="../modules/backbone.d.ts"/>
export class EntityModel extends Backbone.Model{
}
```

EntityCollection.ts

```
/// <reference path="../modules/backbone.d.ts"/>
import em = module("../models/EntityModel");
export class EntityCollection extends Backbone.Collection{
   model = em.EntityModel;
}
```

I get an error message:

public member 'model' of exported class has or is using private type 'em'

I just want to tell it what type of model to use for my collection, but seem to be falling at the first hurdle!

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer: http://typescript.codeplex.com/discussions/405800

Export your imports!

```
export import em = module("../models/EntityModel");
export class EntityCollection extends Backbone.Collection{
   model = em.EntityModel;
}
```

Comment: For the record, the `export import` work-around is only temporary until the bug is fixed. It is also likely that `export import` will be made invalid in a later release - so this work-around will probably only be valid in version 0.8.1.1 of TypeScript.